# SetWindowsHookEx, Keyboard Hooking

Tags: c#, c++, powershell, keyboard, window

I created simple console in C# that uses SetWindowsHookEx and LowLevelKeyboardProc to capture  keyboard events and log them on Windows.

This works perectly, however I know want to create another application that simulates keyboard events in way  that the aformationed application can catch them.

I have attempted to use the 'SendKeys' in powershell but this doesnt seem to work (i.e LowLevelKeyboardProc  wont get triggred).

Any ideas what I can use to simulate keyboard presses such that LowLevelKeyboardProc  gets triggred?

(I am comftable with C++ C# and Powershell)

Answer (score 0):

How about try to use this: https://github.com/jasonpang/Interceptor?  C# wrapper for a Windows keyboard driver. Can simulate keystrokes and mouse clicks in protected areas like the Windows logon screen (and yes, even in games).